# How to do responsive wrapper in HTML/CSS?

Tags: html, css, responsive-design, wrapper

This is how the wrapper is in full width

[image]

But when i minimize the screen to an mobile formate the wrapper looks like this

[image]

You see there is a black area. I want the red side bars to fill it up so it won't be black.

```css
.body {
  overflow: hidden;
}
#wrapper {
  max-width: 1520px;
  height: 880px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  background-color: black;
  width: 100%;
}
#mcontent {
  min-width: 500px;
  max-width: 1520px;
  height: 500px;
  width: auto;
  background-color: fuchsia;
  overflow: hidden;
  padding:
}
#rscontent {
  max-width: 200px;
  min-width: 100px;
  height: 500px;
  background-color: red;
  float:right;
  display: inline-block;
  width: auto;
}
#lscontent {
  max-width: 200px;
  min-width: 100px;
  height: 500px;
  background-color: red;
  float:left;
  display: inline-block;
  width: auto;
}
#content {
  height: 400px;
  max-width: 1920px;
  width: auto;
  background-color: darkviolet;
}
#content > h2 {
  color:blue;
  text-align: center;
  width: auto;
}
#content > p {
  text-align: center;
}
#content > h3 {
  text-align: center;
}
#content > h4 {
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div id="wrapper"> 
  <div id="content">
    <h2>AgencyGaming</h2>
    <h3>Slogan</h3>
    <h4>Information</h4>
  </div>
  <div id="rscontent"></div>
  <div id="lscontent"></div>
  <div id="mcontent">
    <h2 style="color:white;">Hej</h2>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Content has min-width of 500px. It will work fine in desktop but in mobile format the width of window is less than 500px and the width of `#mcontent` div will be reduce unto 500px. It will not reduce than 500px due to `min-width:500px`, so the `#mcontent` div goes on next line.

Comment: Please do not post bare code, also provide an explanation for what the code is doing.

Comment: content has min-width of 500px. It will work fine in desktop but in mobile format the width of window is less than 500px and the width of "#mcontent" div will be reduce unto 500px. It will not reduce than 500px due to min-width:500px, so the "#mcontent" div goes on next line.

Comment: Good explanation, but edit your answer and put the explanation there. Shoot me a comment when you do and I'll toss you a +1.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the `min-width` setting on your left and right side divs.

Answer (score 0):

You could also use **Flexbox** to achieve your desired layout with the following code

**HTML**

```
<div id="wrapper"> 
  <div id="content">
    <h2>AgencyGaming</h2>
    <h3>Slogan</h3>
    <h4>Information</h4>
  </div>
  <div id="rscontent"></div>
  <div id="mcontent">
    <h2 style="color:white;">Hej</h2>
  </div>
  <div id="lscontent"></div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
#wrapper {
  max-width: 1520px;
  background-color: black;
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

#mcontent {
  flex: 1;
  background-color: fuchsia;
  min-height: 500px;
}

#rscontent, #lscontent {
  max-width: 200px;
  min-width: 100px;
  background-color: red;
}

#content {
  flex: 0 0 100%;
  min-height: 400px;
  text-align: center;
  background-color: darkviolet;
}

#content > h2 {
  color:blue;
}
```

```css
#wrapper {
  max-width: 1520px;
  background-color: black;
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}
#mcontent {
  flex: 1;
  background-color: fuchsia;
  min-height: 500px;
}
#rscontent,
#lscontent {
  max-width: 200px;
  min-width: 100px;
  background-color: red;
}
#content {
  flex: 0 0 100%;
  min-height: 400px;
  text-align: center;
  background-color: darkviolet;
}
#content > h2 {
  color: blue;
}
```

```html
<div id="wrapper">
  <div id="content">
    <h2>AgencyGaming</h2>
    <h3>Slogan</h3>
    <h4>Information</h4>
  </div>
  <div id="rscontent"></div>
  <div id="mcontent">
    <h2 style="color:white;">Hej</h2>
  </div>
  <div id="lscontent"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I advice you remove `min-width` from `#mcontent` and try to use `width` in `%` for it instead of `px` or reduce the `min-width` to at least `200px`.